# How can I use multiple parameter on kubernetes CLI?

Tags: kubernetes

I am seeking to how to be able to use multiple parameter on kubernetes. For example:

```
kubectl get pods -n default || kube-system
```

(but the results of this query come out only the result of default namespace).

How can I use multiple params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't query for multiple namespaces resources in one command.
As there is explanation why it is not worth to do that on this [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52326)

But you can query for multiple resources across one or `--all-namespaces`. For example got get `services` and `pods` for namespace `kube-dns` and `default`(this will include workaround as @PEkambaram suggested)

```
kubectl get svc,pods --all-namespaces |egrep -e 'kube-dns|default'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
kubectl get po --all-namespaces | grep kube-system
```

or even better

```
kubectl get po --all-namespaces | grep -iE 'dns|api'
```